# Default value for integer column in SQL query to all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this query, what value that I can use it in the `@vehicleInfoID` parameter to return all rows?

```
DECLARE @vehicleInfoID int = 6

SELECT 
    dr.drID, dc.dcName, dr.drDescription, dr.drIssueDate, 
    dr.drExpiryDate, dr.drNote 
FROM 
    dbo.DocumentRegistration AS dr
LEFT JOIN  
    dbo.Documents AS dc ON dc.dcID = dr.drDocument          
WHERE
    dr.drVehicleInfo = @vehicleInfoID
ORDER BY 
    CAST(dr.drID AS INT) DESC
```

I try this but it's not working !

Comment: You want a [catch all](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)/[kitchen sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) query.